# Issue with PUT when using custom id in JSON server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json-server

I am trying out JSON  server. I have a basic question w.r.t to using "customids" in our api and not "id". Below is my setup

I have an employees endpoint with employeeid as the id(and not using id)

1)db.json looks like

```
             "employees": [
               {
                 "employeeid": 1,
                 "fname": "manju",
                 "lname": "s"
               },
               {
                 "employeeid": 2,
                 "fname": "albert",
                 "lname": "dawson"
               },{
    "fname": "ramesh",
    "lname": "watsons",
    "employeeid": 3  }]
```

2)started json server using
**json-server --id  employeeid  db.json**

3)if I do a POST it generates employeeid automatically as expected.All good until here

4)If I do a PUT without sending the employee id then it removes the employee id completely
What I mean is,say if i want to update first name of employee id 2 (say from albert to albertin) and I send below in PUT body

**PUT URL**
http://localhost:3000/employees/2

**PUT Body** (no employeeeid sent.since it's sent in the URL)
{
"fname": "albertin",
"lname": "dawson"
}

PUT runs successfully but if I do a GET I get the below result **(employee id disappeared)**

````
    {
        "employeeid": 1,
        "fname": "manju",
        "lname": "s"
    },
    {
        "fname": "albertin",
        "lname": "dawson"
    },
    {
        "fname": "ramesh",
        "lname": "watsons",
        "employeeid": 3  }
]```
  
however, if I used an "id" instead of employeeid this used to work fine. Can anyone please explain if we can avoid sending employeeid in the body again

thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```js
const employer = [{
    "employeeid": 1,
    "fname": "manju",
    "lname": "s"
  },
  {
    "employeeid": 2,
    "fname": "albert",
    "lname": "dawson"
  }, {
    "fname": "ramesh",
    "lname": "watsons",
    "employeeid": 3
  }
]

const newdata = {
    "employeeid": 2,
    "fname": "new albert",
    "lname": "dawson"
}

const update = employer.map((x) => x.fname === "albert" ? newdata : x)

console.log(update)
```

Comment: sry not sure if my question was misunderstood. What I actually meant is making a PUT call using POSTMAN. so when u do a PUT i have to send all details including the employeeid in the body. My question was is there a way not to send "employeeid" in the body as i am already sending it in the URL

Comment: sorry you mean I don't understand, maybe you mean for example http: // localhost: 8000 / employer / {id} / You don't want to post the id in the url, maybe you can use params as an alternative

Comment: you can display more you problem

Comment: look at my point 4 above in my orignal question. What i do is in
PUT i send URL as http://localhost:3000/employees/2 where 2 is the employee id which needs to be updated

PUT BODY i send without the employee id
and if you look at the response i attached, json server removes employee id 2 from the response completely

However, if i had used "id" instead of "employeeid" it doesnt remove "id" from the response. Is it anything specific to  JSON server?

Comment: hi, you can use body as params body {"id": Employerid} but you have to remove the params url as http: // localhost: 8000 / employer / and then get the params id from the body

Comment: ok thanks look like that is the only way..what was happening is when I used a the property id (and not employee id) then even if i don't send the id in the body of PUT  it was udating the values and even retaining the id. anyway thanks again :-)

Comment: you can change put as an post because put you must have params